# Get distance from top of window on scroll with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to make an element move a little slower than the rest of the window scroll (parallax if you like)...

I'm using the following...

```
$(window).scroll(function() { 

    'use strict';

    console.log($('section').offset().top);

    $('img').css({
       'margin-top' : -($('section').offset().top/3)+"px",
    });

});
```

Only the section offset remains static throughout the scroll at 130px whereas it should constantly be changing?

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the function you are looking for is $(window).scrollTop() which will return the amount the page is scrolled down at any given point.

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Comment: Of course, the forest can be dense in the oddest of places sometimes :).